# ListView attempting to refresh after exit from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop

We have run into something really weird on Lollipop.

We have a search screen, a list screen and then a details screen.

After performing a search the list is displayed. The user can then choose one entry and get further details.
Everything works great on Android versions up to KK.

However, in Lollipop when exiting from the list screen back to the search screen we sometimes get a crash.
This happens in the getCount() of the list adapter - it is trying to access a item that we have set to null.

What I don't understand is why would it be updating the list view AFTER exiting the activity.
To check the order of actions I registered a ActivityLifecycleCallbacks and printed out the entries to each one.

What I see is the following (when going from the details screen --> list screen --> search screen.

```
onActivityPaused    com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSearchScreen@43db605
onActivityCreated   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityStarted   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityResumed   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityStopped   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSearchScreen@43db605
onActivityPaused    com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityCreated   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityStarted   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityResumed   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityStopped   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityPaused    com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityStarted   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityResumed   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityStopped   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityDestroyed com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSwipeableDetailsScreen@35b3ff59
onActivityPaused    com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorListScreen@108d4747
onActivityStarted   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSearchScreen@43db605
onActivityResumed   com.applicat.meuchedet.DoctorSearchScreen@43db605
```

As can be seen, when going from the details activity to the list activity all is ok - it pauses the details activity then resumes the list activity and finally stops and destroys the details activity.

However, when moving from the list to the search it doesn't reach the stop and destroy of the list activity.
The search activity is resumes and it IS displayed and then the application crashes due to the list activity trying to update something in the adapter.
What's even weirder is that it doesn't happen every time even on Lollipop.

Connecting the adapter to the listview:

```
        this._adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewGroup>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1) {
        // We want to force at least NUM_OF_ITEMS_DISPLAYED rows on the screen. So, we set getCount to return NUM_OF_ITEMS_DISPLAYED
        // if there are less than NUM_OF_ITEMS_DISPLAYED rows.
        // getView then chooses the required view for the row depending on whether it is a row with data or an empty one.
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Math.max(ListScreen.this._maxNumOfItemsToDisplay, ListScreen.this.getActualNumOfItemsInList());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Update the number of items that are visible as this screen is displayed:
            ListScreen.this._numOfItemsDisplayedOnStart = Math.max(ListScreen.this._numOfItemsDisplayedOnStart, position);

            // Choose the view to use depending on the type of row to be displayed
            // The input convertview, if it is not null, will always be the one that matches the type given.
            // This is due to the code in getItemViewType returning the type of view required for this row.
            int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
            boolean isEnabled = itemIsClickable(position);

            switch (viewType){
                case ROW_WITH_DATA:  // Normal data view

                    convertView = ListScreen.this.getConvertView(convertView, parent, viewType, position);
                    _viewHolder.position = position;

                    MeuchedetApplication.setBackgroundDrawable(convertView, getResources().getDrawable(isEnabled ? ListScreen.this.getClickableItemBackground() :
                                                                                                                   ListScreen.this.getNonClickableItemBackground()));


                    setRecordData(position, (ViewGroup) convertView, _viewHolder);
                    _viewHolder.setClickable(itemIsClickable(position));
                    break;
                case ROW_WITHOUT_DATA:  // Empty row
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(ListScreen.this.getEmptyItemLayout(), parent, false);
                    }
                    ListScreen.this.makeInvisible(convertView);
                    break;
            }

            if (itemIsClickable(position)) {
                convertView.setClickable(false);
                convertView.setFocusable(false);
            } else {
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        // This method indicates that we have two different view layouts with the ListView.
        // In our case, one if for the normal row and one is for the empty row
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        // This method returns which type of view to use for which row.
        // We will use the normal type for the original rows and the empty type for any overflow rows.
        // So, type 0 = normal, type 1 = empty
        //
        // This method is called automatically by ListView to determine what type of view to fetch from the recycler.
        // It is then called in our getView code to determine what type of view we have or should create.

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position < ListScreen.this._results._resultsList.size()) ? ROW_WITH_DATA : ROW_WITHOUT_DATA;
        }
    };
    _lv.setAdapter(this._adapter);
```

Where "getConvertView" is a method that fetches the filled view for this row. This method is overridden in classes that extend this one.

Comment: `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are not guaranteed to be called at all. And Android can call them whenever it wants to. Why is the adapter in the List activity trying to do something while that activity is still paused?

Comment: I destroy the data in onPause() but I don't do notifyDatasetChanged or anything like that. Also, I I mentioned, this only happens on Lollipop devices.

Comment: You shouldn't destroy the data in `onPause()`. User can always take a phone call and then return to your app. And if you modify the data you must call `onNotidyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: I only destroy it is isFinishing() returns true.

Comment: Sounds fishy. Please post the code in your activity where you create the adapter and set the adapter on the Viewin ListActivity.